# Why do applications that present color palettes sometimes restrict the colors to shades of gray?

Tags: macos, colors, osx-lion, adobe-illustrator, color-profiles

I've noticed that sometimes on OS X, Adobe Illustrator's color palette only shows shades of gray rather than a full range of colors.  If this occurred in Photoshop, I'd immediately assume the document was somehow set to Grayscale; however, I don't see such a setting in AI.  Even so, when it has occurred I assumed that I bumped some keyboard shortcut and changed the mode or even more likely that the application had a bug.  However, I recently saw the exact same problem occur in another application, OmniGroup's Outliner.  There is a panel/palette to change color of text or rows and the palette(s) appeared to be grayscale only.

Is this a bug in OS X, a bug that coincidentally exist in both applications, or is there a system-wide setting that I'm somehow toggling?

Comment: I thought Illustrator had a custom color palette.

Comment: @Nano8Blazex At least Photoshop has a preference for *Color Picker: Adobe / Apple*

Comment: @Lri Oh, ok. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second tab of the OS X color picker shows *Gray Scale Slider* by default:

[image]

In an Adobe CS color picker you could've accidentally selected the radio box for saturation:

[image]

I don't know if it was either of these, but I've often been confused by both myself.

Comment: I see!  Thank you!  It's possible that I bumped ⌘1